# losing class information when using replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a quiz in javascript and using the jQuery.replaceWith() function to replace one div with another.  The text looks right after the replace, but the click events don't work. Its seems like the new elements aren't being recognized as being members of the specified classes.

Here's what I have (only including the relevant part):

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="quiz_box grid_12" id="quiz">
        <div class = "question_box">
            <span = "que_span">
                <p class="question">Test Question 1</p>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class = "answer_box grid_12">
            <span class = "ans_span">
                <p class="correct">Test Answer 1</p>
                <p class="incorrect">Test Answer 2</p>
                <p class="incorrect">Test Answer 3</p>
                <p class="incorrect">Test Answer 4</p>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class = "response_box grid_12">
                <p class = "response">Test Default Response</p>
        </div>
        <img src="images/next.png" class="quiz_button" id="next_button" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

quiz.js

```
var q1Answers=
   '<div class = "answer_box grid_12">
    <p class="correct">Test Answer 5</p>
    <p class="incorrect">Test Answer 6</p>
    <p class="incorrect">Test Answer 7</p>
    <p class="incorrect">Test Answer 8</p>
    </div>';
var current_question = 0;
var questions = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12];
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("Ready");

$("#next_button").click(function(){
    if(current_question < questions.length){
    $(".question").replaceWith($(questions[current_question]));
    $(".answer_box").replaceWith($(q1Answers));
    current_question +=1;
    }
});

$('.correct').click(function(e){
    alert("correct");
});

$(".incorrect").click(function(){
    alert("incorrect");
});
});
```

So the first questions (Test Question 1-4) are written into the html and call the correct/incorrect alerts when clicked.  The replacement questions (5-8) will appear when the next button is hit, but their click events for correct/incorrect no longer function. Any Idea?

Comment: Aameer - Thanks for the reply.  Wouldn't the $(".correct").click function be connected to anything that includes class="correct" in the tag?

Comment: karan - I copied and pasted in chunks, so the missing quotes are just a copy/paste error.  Thanks.

Comment: yes, but only the elements that are present in de DOM at that time. Better use .on(), which is able to bind current and future elements that match the selector. See for more info: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Adeneo - Thanks that explains exactly what my problem is. Walter - I'll look into the .on function.  Thank you all for the quick response!

Comment: Beautiful!  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you replace an element, you remove the one that is currently there, and insert a new one.

The way event handlers work is that they are bound to certain elements, not the selector itself, which is just a string, so when the element is removed, so is the bound event handler, even if a new element with the same class is inserted in it's place, it's not the same element, and does not have the same event handlers.

There really is no way to bind an event handler to an element that doesn't exist in the DOM, but to solve the issue you could delegate the event handlers to an element that is not removed

```
$('#quiz').on('click', '.correct', function(e){
    alert("correct");
});

$('#quiz').on('click', '.incorrect', function(){
    alert("incorrect");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you copy paste this ? missing the closing quote in

```
var q1Answers='<div class = "answer_box grid_12>
```